# Why "(502) Bad Gateway" error happen?

Tags: c#, .net

Windows 7 SP1.
Domain network.
.NET Framework 4.6.1.

All my Internet browsers have configured proxy settings for Internet connections (it works fine).

I need to download file from Internet. I configure `WebClient` for it will read proxy settings from default Internet browser and use credential of current process and I expected these conditions are enough for successfull downloading. But I get the exception (look the comment in my code):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    String file_name = Path.GetRandomFileName();
    String full_path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
        Path.Combine(@"%LocalAppData%\Temp", file_name));

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //client.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        var proxyUri = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
            .GetProxy(new Uri("https://yadi.sk/i/jPScGsw9qiSXU"));

        try {                    
            client.DownloadFile(proxyUri, full_path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

What I did wrong?

[image]

Comment: That's weird, what you are doing should work. Have you tried a web debugger like fiddler to see what request is actually being sent?

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your app.config? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11787116/2330575

Comment: I updated my code (now I have other error message). I newer used web debugger before. It is usual console application.

Comment: The code should be  client.DownloadFile("https://yadi.sk/i/jPScGsw9qiSXU", full_path); and client.Proxy = proxyUri.

Comment: @gabriel, but I did the same in my code: `client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Comment: @gldraphael, no, I got the same problem. @gabriel the `client.Proxy` and `proxyUri` have different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the proxy for the specific URL then set it as the proxy URL of the web request.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    String file_name = Path.GetRandomFileName();
    String full_path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
        Path.Combine(@"%LocalAppData%\Temp", file_name));

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var proxyUri = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
            .GetProxy(new Uri("https://yadi.sk/i/jPScGsw9qiSXU"));
        client.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri);
        client.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        try {                    
            client.DownloadFile("https://yadi.sk/i/jPScGsw9qiSXU", full_path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is implemented just in case the proxy uri is different depending on the url you are trying to access.

Comment: Thank you, but I got the same problem again.

Comment: `proxyUri` is instance of `Uri`, but `client.Proxy` is instance of  `IWebProxy`.

Comment: Also now I got other exception: *The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.* :(((

Comment: Please see latest update, you need to set the proxy uri as the proxy of the client.

Comment: For your variant I get error: *The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.* Why do you use "https://yadi.sk/i/jPScGsw9qiSXU" string twice?

Comment: You can store it in a variable up top. The GetProxy method will get the system proxy url based on the url you are trying to access. This can differ in certain proxy configurations e.g. accessing internal sites generally bypass proxies. Can you please add a breakpoint just before the DownloadFile call and confirm the proxyUri is what is set in IE?

Comment: Please see latest update, you need to set the credentials of the proxy to the default credentials.