# System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml - Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a piece of old code (a single .aspx file) that I need to get through a proxy.  This code used to work, but now the company have tightened up on security.

The offending line of code is:

```
dataSet.ReadXml(url);
```

The url is https.

It is running on .NET version 2.0 - this cannot be upgraded.
I cannot change the web.config file.

What do I need to add to the .aspx file to get it to work?
The error I am getting is:

```
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

There is no "connecting to the web" code in the script.

*EDIT*

Based on Dan's comment, I have tried this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
IWebProxy proxy = request.Proxy;                    
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
Uri newUri = new Uri("http://10.79.30.190:8080");
// Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
myProxy.Address = newUri;
// Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
// Proxy property of request object.
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Proxy = myProxy;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(responseString);
```

but am still getting the same error

*EDIT*

Another attempt:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
IWebProxy proxy = request.Proxy;                    
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
Uri newUri = new Uri("http://10.79.30.190:8080");
// Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
myProxy.Address = newUri;
// Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
// Proxy property of request object.
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Proxy = myProxy;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));
```

but am still getting the same error

Comment: You will need to fetch the file using [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar, specifying proxy credentials, and then parse it as XML. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9603791/3608792.

Comment: have you tried default credentials? `request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means, that your credentials for the proxy server are incorrect, best solution to try and approach this problem would be:

**First, add this line to your** `Web.Config`:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

**Second, is through code**:

```
service.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; ;
service.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

**third, is to set the credentials in two locations through code**:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uirTradeStream) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

it's whatever suits you best here.

Comment: Turns out it was a firewall issue.  I switched proxies (I'm guessing on a different firewall) and it worked.  The error message in this case is misleading, but I'll give you the points for trying to help anyway :-)