# How do I do a WebRequest.Create through a proxy?

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest

Our program checks for updates by doing a POST to a url on our website which returns an XML response that has the latest version number. Works great unless there is a proxy server.

1. How do I programatically determine if there is a proxy server?
2. What do I need to then do to work through the proxy server?

We are presently using WebRequset.Create().

More details. The proxy log where this is happening shows:

> AutoTag sends
>   HEAD http://update.windward.net/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: update.windward.net
>
> and gets response with status code 407.

thanks - dave

Comment: HttpWebRequest [does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155363/how-to-autodetect-use-ie-proxy-settings-in-net-httpwebrequest) use the configured proxy server.

Comment: If they haven't set this, or don't use IE, they could then hit this problem - correct?

Comment: Correct, but why would someone install a proxy server on their network and not inform the clients about that? It makes internet connectivity a little bit troublesome.

Comment: @CodeCaster - got me but it's like elementary particle physics, anything that can happen does happen somewhere. We have never had a user hit this before so clearly it works fine for most. But for one it's a problem.

Comment: Then how does that user browse the internet in his environment?

Comment: @CodeCaster - Probably using a browser that does not set the proxy settings. Or it might be a VM used just for development and he browses from his host O/S.