# In C#, can you find what proxy server your computer is using?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, proxy

I've noticed some programs (such as IE and Firefox) can automatically detect a network proxy server to use for Internet traffic.  Is it possible to do the same in C#?  Are there APIs for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) or possibly [WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx). This should be able to pick up whatever IE detects.

Also, [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112320/removing-obsolete-webproxy-getdefaultproxy-references/1112399#1112399) indicate that `HttpWebRequest` will go through your system proxy by default.

Comment: DefaultWebProxy reads proxy settings from the app.config file. If there is no config file, IE proxy settings are used. GetSystemWebProxy read directly IE settings.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpWebRequest.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx)

Comment: I don't see that API, but there's others in that class that do the trick nicely.  Maybe .NET 4 renamed it or something.

Comment: Oh, looks like it's an instance method.  I'll trust it works, though the static methods above seem to work just as well.

Comment: HttpWebRequest.Proxy is a property that lets you determine which proxy you want the given request to use. It defaults to the system proxy though so it's roughly equivalent to using the static property.